# Unable to push helm charts to JFrog Artifactory: 'not a valid chart repository' error

Tags: devops, kubernetes-helm, artifactory

I am trying to add the helm repository to my JFrog account but it is giving me an error. I have created a remote repository.

How can I push using helm client?

```
helm repo add <key> https://ip/artifactory/<key> --username username --password password
```

> Error: looks like "https://ip/artifactory/" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://ip/artifactory//index.yaml : 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot push to a remote repository. It's meant to proxy and cache remote repositories only. Not to allow you to push your artifacts to them via Artifactory.

If you look into the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Kubernetes+Helm+Chart+Repositories), you'll see you need to have a virtual, local and remote helm repositories.

For example:

```
helm-local  -> your local repo
helm-remote -> your remote repo
helm        -> your virtual repo
```

For the virtual repository, you set the [default deployment repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Kubernetes+Helm+Chart+Repositories#KubernetesHelmChartRepositories-DeployingHelmCharts) (where the charts you upload are pushed to). This would be the local repository you created.

Once you have them setup, you do the login against the virtual repository - `https://ip/artifactory/helm`. The `helm repo add` command uses this URL.

Comment: So basically I have to create 3 repository helm-local, helm-remote, helm right?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says, you cannot push to artifactory with helm. You need JFrog CLI (https://jfrog.com/blog/master-helm-chart-repositories-artifactory/)

1. Create a local helm repository with id `helm-local`
2. Install jfrog CLI
3. Run

```bash
jfrog rt u your-helm-chart-package.tgz helm-local
```

4. When ask for initial setup, confirm and configure your artifactory.

```
Configure now? (y/n) [n]? y
Choose a server ID: artifactory
JFrog Platform URL: https://your-artifactory.fqdn.example.com/
JFrog username: admin-user-name
JFrog password or API key:
```

When done, you get a success message:

```
These files were uploaded:

 helm-local
└──  your-helm-chart-package.tgz

{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```